# How do I convert an object to JSON representation

Tags: java, json

Oddly enough, I didn't find this.

What's the simplest way to convert an object to a JSON string? (Edge cases like loops in the object graphs aren't of much interest to me. Let's find a solution to the simple case of class A that contains some objects of classes B,C,D and some primitives).

Basic collection support is a must.

Answer (score 5):

Heh, I discovered/remembered what we are already using for this.

[ObjectMapper](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.4.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html) from CodeHaus

The code looks like this - super simple:

```
Object obj = ...
String result = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
```

Comment: That works. One suggestion: if you do this in many places, make sure to reuse ObjectMapper instances... they are expensive to create.

Comment: @StaxMan - indeed, I was just demoing a simple usage. Now, I have to wonder if reusing is thread safe.

Comment: Yes, figured that's the case; but just in case someone wanted to cut'n paste code. And yes, reuse is safe, as per: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonBestPracticeThreadSafety

Answer (score 2):

[**Gson**](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) from google is good for me . It works with collections and generics and converts both ways.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend JAXB + Jackson. Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071749/how-to-reuse-jerseys-json-jaxb-for-serialization) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

See answer here: [Javascript to Java using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792315/javascript-to-java-using-json/3794212#3794212)

The answer applies both ways, they're bi-directional.